# Nuxt 3 publicRuntimeConfig always undefined

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've upgraded Nuxt to V3 and I've switched to `publicRuntimeConfig`

nuxt.config.js

```
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    BASE_API_URL: '${BASE_API_URL}'|| 'http://localhost/api',
    BASE_API_BROWSER_URL: '${BASE_API_BROWSER_URL}'
  }
```

and then on the page I have this simple code, which doesn't work either with `$config`

```
<script setup>
const { data:name } = await useAsyncData( 'name', () => $fetch( config.BASE_API_BROWSER_URL+'/message') );
</script>
```

the only way to make it work is by hardcoding the URL "http://localhost/api/message" instead of the ENV.

I tried to print out `$config` on the page and this is what I get back

```
{ "public": {}, "app": { "baseURL": "/", "buildAssetsDir": "/_nuxt/", "cdnURL": "" } }
```

Any way to make it work?

this is the [GitHub pubblic repo](https://github.com/sebalaini/laravel_docker-compose)

Comment: The variables you're defining there are supposed to be private? Give a try to that one: https://nuxt.com/docs/migration/runtime-config#example

Comment: they are public, do you have a link to a non TS Nuxt? I use the old js file

Comment: There is no difference, in that case, the code is the same as TS or JS. Also, if it's public it should instead be `NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_API_URL`.

Comment: OK, I've updated the nuxt.confix.js with the code from the docs you posted and now seems to work, I'm using now this code in the page `const { data: app } = await useFetch(${runtimeConfig.public.BASE_API_BROWSER_URL}/message, { pick: ['name'] })` though the result seems to be printed only if I made some changes in the code and then the HMR return the data else is always empty :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `runtimeConfig` instead of `publicRuntimeConfig` ([docs/migration](https://nuxt.com/docs/migration/runtime-config#example)):

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
runtimeConfig: {
  // Config within public will be also exposed to the client
  public: {
    BASE_API_URL: '${BASE_API_URL}'|| 'http://localhost/api',
    BASE_API_BROWSER_URL: '${BASE_API_BROWSER_URL}'
  }
},
```

And then, use it in the setup function:

`your-component.vue`

```html
<script setup>
const baseApiUrl = useRuntimeConfig().public.BASE_API_URL;
</script>
```